# Parsing a URL query object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to create a function that will use an object passed in the url. The goal is to update menu items for a restaurant. The query sent will look like this:

`?restId=1&posId=1&groups=…&items= [{"id":"000101","price":2500,"desc":"ארוחת ראפ","count":0,"status":0,"type":0,"group":1,"variations":[]},{"id":"000145","price":7980,"desc":"ארוחת בוקר ילדים","count":0,"status":0,"type":1,"group":1,"variations":[{"desc":"LEVEL 1","level":1,"maxNumAllowed":1,"items":[{"id":"000119","price":500,"desc":"ספריבס כבש טרי","count":0,"type":0,"group":1,"variations":[]},{"id":"000117","price":0,"desc":"פילה עוף טרי","count":0,"type":0,"group":1,"variations":[]},{"id":"000166","price":0,"desc":"שישליק הודו טרי","count":0,"type":0,"group":1,"variations":[]}]&pizzas=[{"id":"100250","desc":"מגש משפחתית","slices":4,"price":6400,"count":1,"group":3,"toppingPolicy":[{"id":"100112","desc":"תוספת גבינה","pricing":[{"slicesCount":1,"price":200},{"slicesCount":2,"price":400},{"slicesCount":3,"price":600},{"slicesCount":4,"price":800}]},{"id":"100111","desc":"ללא גבינה","pricing":[{"slicesCount":1,"price":0},{"slicesCount":2,"price":0},{"slicesCount":3,"price":0},{"slicesCount":4,"price":0}]},{"id":"100110","desc":"ללא רוטב","pricing":[{"slicesCount":1,"price":0},{"slicesCount":2,"price":0},{"slicesCount":3,"price":0},{"slicesCount":4,"price":0}]}],"discountable":true}]`

When I run `const queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;` it prints:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  restId: '1',
  posId: '1',
  groups: '…',
  items: ' [{"id":"000101","price":2500,"desc":"ארוחת ראפ","count":0,"status":0,"type":0,"group":1,"variations":[]},{"id":"000145","price":7980,"desc":"ארוחת בוקר ילדים","count":0,"status":0,"type":1,"group":1,"variations":[{"desc":"LEVEL 1","level":1,"maxNumAllowed":1,"items":[{"id":"000119","price":500,"desc":"ספריבס כבש טרי","count":0,"type":0,"group":1,"variations":[]},{"id":"000117","price":0,"desc":"פילה עוף טרי","count":0,"type":0,"group":1,"variations":[]},{"id":"000166","price":0,"desc":"שישליק הודו טרי","count":0,"type":0,"group":1,"variations":[]}]',
  pizzas: '[{"id":"100250","desc":"מגש משפחתית","slices":4,"price":6400,"count":1,"group":3,"toppingPolicy":[{"id":"100112","desc":"תוספת גבינה","pricing":[{"slicesCount":1,"price":200},{"slicesCount":2,"price":400},{"slicesCount":3,"price":600},{"slicesCount":4,"price":800}]},{"id":"100111","desc":"ללא גבינה","pricing":[{"slicesCount":1,"price":0},{"slicesCount":2,"price":0},{"slicesCount":3,"price":0},{"slicesCount":4,"price":0}]},{"id":"100110","desc":"ללא רוטב","pricing":[{"slicesCount":1,"price":0},{"slicesCount":2,"price":0},{"slicesCount":3,"price":0},{"slicesCount":4,"price":0}]}],"discountable":true}]'
}
```

My problem is that I cannot access any of the values in items. I was given this url, so I cannot change it at all. How can I parse items in order to access the values?

Comment: You need to parse the JSON string before treating it as an object: `const stuffYouCanWorkWith = JSON.parse(queryObject.items);`

Comment: The items object is not valid json, so that does not return a useable object.

Comment: _"The items object is not valid json..."_ - Then you might want to fix that first...

Answer (score 0):

The value of `items` and `pizzas` are both JSON formatted strings. You have to parse them to access the contained data. This is accomplished by calling `JSON.parse()`

So in your case, to access `items`, you could do the following:

`const items = JSON.parse(queryObject.items)`

The only problem you have now is that `items` isn't actually a valid JSON string. It's missing four closing tags `}]}]` at the end. I'm not sure if that's a transcription error or if you're actually getting a malformed URL, but that will cause you issues if the URL in your question is accurate.